# How to keep updating data in local storage JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am getting a value from a text field and store it in local storage because I need to show the same value typed by the user back to the text field after some validation. Once the value is stored it doesn't update itself because every time I change the value in the text field I expect to store the same value in the local storage but it only does it one and displays the same value every time it stored the first time.

jsp

```
<s:textfield name="emailId" id="emailId" label="Email" cssClass="dataFieldCell3" value="%{#signerslist.email}"  />
```

JS

setting the variable in local storage

```
function showEmail() {
    var email = document.getElementById("emailId").value;
    localStorage.setItem("invalidEmail", email);
}
```

getting it and assign it back in the text field

```
function emailValidationErrorMessage() {
    if('${emailValidationMessage}' !== "") {
        $("#Signers").show();
        var getEmailValue = localStorage.getItem("invalidEmail");
        document.getElementById("emailId").value = getEmailValue;
    }
}
```

Please guide...

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you using localStorage and not just a regular event handler ?

Comment: I thought this is the only way so used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...every time I change the value in the text field I expect to store
>   the same value in the local storage...

Then, the `showEmail` function needs to be set as the callback function for the text field's **[`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)** event so that `localStorage` will be updated each time the user changes the value in the text field.

```
document.getElementById("emailId").addEventListener("change", showEmail);
```

Comment: Scott! where so you want me to add this line?

Comment: @Mike This should be added to your JavaScript that executes after the web page has finished loading, so you could put it into a `script` that comes just before the closing `body` tag.

Comment: You are awesome. It worked like a charm. Thank you so much.